# Checking app version from market place in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I need to compare current app version and market place app version.

```
if (CurrentAppVersion() < MarketPlaceAppVersion()) {
                MessageBox.Show("You need to update your app");
            }

private int CurrentAppVersion() {
            return 0;
        }

        private int MarketPlaceAppVersion() {
            return 0;
        }
```

I got a [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833354/how-to-get-app-version-in-windows-phone) to check current app version. How can I get market place app version.

Comment: Check this: http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Checking_for_updates_from_inside_a_Windows_Phone_app

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this feature by myself but i have seen this in an open source toolkit named  cimbalino you can find it at http://cimbalino.org/

its source is available on github at https://github.com/Cimbalino/Cimbalino-Phone-Toolkit

Following Nokia developer post describes that how it actually works 
http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Checking_for_updates_from_inside_a_Windows_Phone_app