# How to get the version of a Windows Phone 8.1 app in code?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Is it possible to get the version of the app while it's running?

In a Windows desktop application I can get it as follows:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
```

But `GetExecutingAssembly()` isn't available in Windows Phone 8.1.

Is there another way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get app version in Windows Phone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833354/how-to-get-app-version-in-windows-phone)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. That is for Windows Phone 8.0. There's a substantial difference between 8.0 and 8.1, and the accepted answer does not work in Windows Phone 8.1.

Comment: using System.Reflection;
...
typeof(Class).GetTypeInfo().Assembly

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is how:

```
PackageVersion pv = Package.Current.Id.Version;
Version version = new Version(Package.Current.Id.Version.Major, 
    Package.Current.Id.Version.Minor, 
    Package.Current.Id.Version.Revision, 
    Package.Current.Id.Version.Build);
```

Comment: Be careful, you're mixing revision and build: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kstyaxxh(v=vs.110).aspx. It might be ```new Version(Package.Current.Id.Version.Major, 
    Package.Current.Id.Version.Minor, 
    Package.Current.Id.Version.Build, 
    Package.Current.Id.Version.Revision);```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the answer above does not work on my project ( maybe because I'm running Windows Phone 10 and the app being targeted for Windows Phone 8.1 ). Since there is people who might have this error too, I'll leave here the solution I've found for my case.

```cs
Type
    type = typeof( App );
TypeInfo
    typeInfo = type.GetTypeInfo();
Assembly
    assembly = typeInfo.Assembly;
AssemblyName
    assemblyName = assembly.GetName();
Version
    version = assemblyName.Version;

String
    versionString = String.Format( "{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}",
        version.Major,
        version.Minor,
        version.Build,
        version.Revision );
```

Or, in a simplified way:

```cs
Version
    version = typeof( App ).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Version;

String
    versionString = String.Format( "{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}",
        version.Major,
        version.Minor,
        version.Build,
        version.Revision );
```

As for an example, while I had `[assembly: AssemblyVersion( "0.1.*" )]` on my `AssemblyInfo.cs`, which would generate a Build and Revision numbers for me, with the `Package.Current.Id.Version` I would get `0.1.0.0` whilst with the method I described above I get `0.1.5918.18756`.