# IsolatedStorageSettings after application update from store

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, updates, isolatedstorage

I am writing my  Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight App (NOT RunTIME framework).
I have to questions:

1. Which is the App manifest file for Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight? WMAppManifest or Package.appxmanifest? as my project contains both
2. I created a method in Mainpage of application which detects that is it the first time this application is running or not. If it is first time execution of this app, registry of 120 keys (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings) is created and app moves to WelcomePage.If the execution is not the firsttime, means user has opened this app before, it skips the registrycreation method and directly goes to homepage.

When I upload this version 1 of app to store and users install and use it. What when I add more keys to registrycreate method in version 2 and upload version 2 to store. How will be those new keys get created? Even, when user updates the app, the registrycreation method will never run.

Comment: IsolatedStorageSettings provide a convenient way to store user specific data as key-value pairs in a local IsolatedStorageFile with an lifespan of the application. So, Windows Phone app will save any data saved after app update.  THAT IS WHERE MY PROBLEM STARTS. What if I have added more keys to my registrycreation method, but that method will never ever run except first time

Answer (score 0):

1. The "Silverlight" app manifest is WMAppManifest.xml, but you still need to include the "RT" manifest Package.appxmanifest and, if you ever use any of the RT namespaces that require certain capabilities, you should check those capabilities in the Package.appxmanifest too. Eg "Internet (Client & Server)" if you are using things like Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer.
2. You'd need to add some code to check if the information or information structure has changed every time the app is run (or resumed), so that in the event of an update (and change in the keys), they get added, even if your "first run" code doesn't fire. Make sense?

Comment: for my second question, I now added key count method. feels like amateur

Comment: for my first question, .. acutally how to detect the app version inside app? from WMAppManifest or Package.appxmanifest?  https://www.pedrolamas.com/2013/07/24/checking-for-updates-from-inside-a-windows-phone-app/

Comment: In WMAppMaifest I believe, however there are a number of ways to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833354/how-to-get-app-version-in-windows-phone

Answer (score 0):

If you know the keys numbers will always get bigger then watching the key count will work. You could also include a key with the version so you can tell which version the data was created with.

You can use Windows.Storage.ApplicationData instead of IsolatedStorageSettings in Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1. ApplicationData supports versioning with the [ApplicationData.SetVersionAsync method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.setversionasync.aspx) so you can change the data format safely when you update the app.

Either way, when the app runs check if the data's version is the latest that the app knows about. If not then run your setup and migration code to add the new keys and replace the out-of-date ones.

The data version doesn't have to match the app version (you may update the app's version without changing the data). You can compile a data version constant into the app's data handling code and bump it whenever you change the data format.