# XmlResolver is not working in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal Apps

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I want to read the Title and Version of my App to XML Reader, How to get Title and Version of my app.

XmlResolver is Working in WP8.0, But when coming to in WP8.1 Universal Apps it is not working.

```
XmlReaderSettings settings2 = new XmlReaderSettings
            {
                XmlResolver = new XmlXapResolver()
            };
```

Comment: "it is not working" doesn't tell us anything about what you're observing. Does it not compile? Does it compile but give the wrong results? An exception? Please give more information.

Comment: Did you tried other methods mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833354/how-to-get-app-version-in-windows-phone?

Comment: To addon, as per the documentation, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.xmlresolver(v=vs.110).aspx, it is supported in WP 8.1. Can you share the error you are getting?

Comment: it is for windows phone but i required in windows phone 8.1 Winrt Universal apps

Answer (score 0):

Best way I found to do this is by using the [Cimbalino toolkit](http://cimbalino.org/)!
It has a ApplicationManifestService with which you can retrieve the ApplicationManifest information.
Like app title and app version.

Check out an example here https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-use-Cimbalino-6d905243